# Get new created process processID Vbscript

Tags: vbscript, process, scripting

I am creating this snippet that executes a calc.exe process and report its processID

```
Option Explicit
Dim objWMIService, objProcess, objCalc
Dim strShell, objProgram, strComputer, strExe ,oMethod, svc, sQuery, cproc, iniproc, ProcID

strComputer = "."
strExe = "Calc.exe"
' Connect to WMI
set objWMIService = getobject("winmgmts://"_
& strComputer & "/root/cimv2") 

' Obtain the Win32_Process class of object.
Set objProcess = objWMIService.Get("Win32_Process")
Set objProgram = objProcess.Methods_( _
"Create").InParameters.SpawnInstance_
objProgram.CommandLine = strExe 

'Execute the program now at the command line.
Set strShell = objWMIService.ExecMethod( _
"Win32_Process", "Create", objProgram) 

ProcID = strShell.ProcessId
WScript.echo "The process ID is" &ProcID
```

I have being validating the process id of the calc.exe opened with proces explorer but it does not match to the info that i am getting.

[image]
¡Any ideas about, ¿why I am getting the wrong process id?

Comment: calculator.exe is an universal app, I think `C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe` is only a stub loading the other. I don't like that calculater.exe at all, my Logitech keyboard has a key for it but never brings the app to front.

Comment: Thanks I testeted it with apps like ping and diskpart ans works fine

Answer (score 2):

The easy way to get process id:

```
set process = GetObject("winmgmts:Win32_Process")
process.Create "calc.exe",null,null,processid
wscript.echo " PID  :   "  & Processid
```